# Slow loading of cljsbuild in Clojure

Tags: clojure, ring, cljsbuild

I'm new to Clojure and I'm trying to setup a development environment where I can dynamically load my web project files using ring-server and cljsbuild

i have the following snippet in my project file

```
:ring {
      :handler cjohansen-no.web/app
      ;;:auto-refresh true
      ;;:auto-reload? true
      ;;:reload-paths ["resources","src"]
      ;;:refresh-paths ["resources","src"]
    }
  :aliases {
        "start-server" ["ring" "server-headless"]
        "build-site" ["run" "-m" "cjohansen-no.web/export"]
        "build-html" ["run" "-m" "cjohansen-no.web/export-pages"]
        "build-js" ["cljsbuild" "auto" "dev"]
        "build-web" ["do" ["build-site"] ["build-js"]]
        "build-dev" ["pdo" ["build-web"] ["start-server"] ["auto" "build-html"]]
            }
  :source-paths ["src"]
  :test-paths ["test/cjohansen_no" "test/cljs" "spec"]
  :clean-targets [:target-path "./build/js/out"
                  :compile-path "classes"
                  :output-paths "./build/js/output"
                  "build/js/main.js.map"
                  ]
  :main cjohansen-no.web
  :clean-non-project-classes true
  :figwheel {
    ;;:server-port 3000
    :css-dirs ["resources/public/css"]
    :reload-clj-files {:clj true :cljc false}
    :ring-handler cjohansen-no.web/app
    :repl false
  }
  :cljsbuild {
    :builds [

      {
      ;; :notify-command ["growlnotify" "-m"]
      :id "dev"
      :source-paths ["src/cljs"]
      :figwheel {
          :websocket-host :js-client-host
          :autoload false
          :reload-dependents true
          :debug true
      }
      :compiler {
             :main scripts.core
             :output-to "resources/public/js/main.js"
             :output-dir "resources/public/js/out"
             :optimizations :none
             :source-map true
             :source-map-timestamp true
             :recompile-dependents false
             :pretty-print true
             :asset-path "js/out"

             ;;:notify-command ["bin/phantomjs"  "bin/speclj.js" "resources/public/js/main.js"]
           }

      }, 
....
}
  :profiles {
            :dev {
                :dependencies [
                  ;;[figwheel "0.5.4-7"]
                ]
                :plugins [
                    [lein-pdo "0.1.1"]
                    [lein-ring "0.9.7"]
                    [lein-cljsbuild "1.1.3"]
                    [lein-figwheel "0.5.4-7"]
                  ]
             }
```

I use this snippet to run my server

```
(def app (->
            (stasis/serve-pages get-pages)
            (optimus/wrap get-assets optimizations/all serve-live-assets)
            ;;(wrap-cljsbuild "/js/" cljsbuild)
             wrap-content-type
             ;; wrap-reload
             wrap-utf-8))
```

I'm loading my assets using Optimus

```
(defn get-assets []
  (concat (assets/load-bundle "public" "styles.css" [#"css/.+\.css$"])
    (assets/load-assets "public" [#"img/.*" "/questions.json"])
    (assets/load-bundle "public" "main.js" [#"js/.+\.js"])
    ))
```

when I run `lein with-profile dev pdf start-server, cljsbuild auto` and bring up my website the js files and its dependants as compiled by the "dev" build takes FOREVER to complete loading. Why is the ring server so slow?

Should I be referencing the build files in this manner? should i bundle it into one file?

The profile used is for development purposes.

Comment: how long is forever?

Comment: assuming you don't have super fasr hardware, 10s is not unreasonable for a Clojurescript cold compile time. That's also why it's so important to you incremental compilation

Comment: 10secs is a lot of live reloading

Comment: It's not live reloading that takes 10s, just cold compile time, which happens about 3 times a day :) on a regular CLJS setup hot code reloading (which is not exactly the same and even better than live reloading) is instantaneous.

Comment: Well i'm new to this clojure stuff so .................sighs

Comment: don't hesitate to ask for help on the community chat: http://clojurians.net/

Answer (score 1):

That is a pretty complex project.clj file if your just starting up and are new to clojure/clojurescript. It is possible that starting with just the bare lein figwheel template might be a good way to get a basic environment and then just add to it once you know you need additional bits. It could be that simply parsing your project file is slowing things down.

The basic figwheel template will set things up so that it all reloads when necessary - there really isn't much extra you need to worry about.